# best php form mailer atm?

Tags: php, html, email, responsive-design

since I have only been working with CMS systems for the past few years I havent had to use a form mailer for quite a while. Now all I need though is a simple php form mailer - ideally already with a responsive web form. I can do that myself though, all I really need is a solid php backend.

Which (free) solution can you guys recommend? Thanks!

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is **primarily opinion-based**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP mailer is best for sending emails. Example code is also included in downloads

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know these kind of questions were ot...